# Structure Question with EF 4.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, ddd-repositories

What are any reccomendations for the following.
I have a structure like this.
--ApplicationServices

--Domain

--Infrastructure.Backends

--Infrastructure.Data

--MVC Web Application

Where should one put the edmx file and generated POCO's? I was thinking domain, if that were the case then the Application services would call the repository and return data to the controllers in the MVC application. Is this the correct mode of thought?

Where do the repository interfaces and implementation of the repository sit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the onion architecture.  http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/

An example of the implementation. http://codecampserver.codeplex.com/

So, to answer your question, I'd put the .edmx in Infrastructure.Data.  Domain can contain your model and interfaces.  Infrastructure.* contains the implementations.

Comment: Ok, so I read about the Onion architecture, if I put the edmx file, which is essentially the model and all of the generated POCOS, in the Infrastructure laye then the interfaces will have to go there as well. We can't have the domain depending on the infrastructure layer as that violates the Onion.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more since to make a place in domain for model and put it there?

Comment: Isn't the edmx the mappings, can't the edmx be split so you have poco's and the edmx contains the mappings?

Comment: But correct, if your model and mappings are in the edmx put it in core.

Comment: Just a follow up. I have put my edmx file in the infrastructure layer and the entites in core. It was hell getting everything split appart but the reults work well. good seperation.